# How to use valid form data to create object in database?

Tags: django

I am trying to create a helper function that validates forms. If the form is valid, then I will create an object in the database. The function takes in three arguments, the request, the form, and the model.

```
def form_validate(request, form, model):
  form = form(request.POST)
  print form
  if form.is_valid():
    print "the form is valid"
    # create object using valid form
  else:
    print "the form is not valid"
    # send back items
    print form.errors.items()
```

If the form is valid, I want to use the form data to create a new model. How would I do that? I have tried to look at the Django docs(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: You should come back to documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Wolever said, using ModelForms is the obvious way.

You could also pass the cleaned_data dictionary to the model constructor (assuming the fields are the same):

```
def form_validate(request, form, model):
    form = form(request.POST)
    print form
    if form.is_valid():
        print "the form is valid"
        obj = model(**form.cleaned_data)
        obj.save()
    else:
        # etc
```

However, ModelForms are really the easiest way of doing this, but you might be interested in reading Django's source to see how they work.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I ran into this from google and still have questions: what do we do if there is no "form", but only form *data* because of a call from an external domain with a payload, so that we *only* have POST data to work with?

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely want to look at ModelForms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/